# TCP socket: detect if peer has shut down before sending? (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

Is there any direct command to detect whether the peer has shut down / closed its socket **before** sending?

I do this:

```
int sendResult = send( mySD, bufferPtr, numberToSend, MSG_NOSIGNAL );
```

`send()` does happily accept the message and seems to send it (positive return value), only the *next* time I try sending it returns an error. That means: I get the warning 1 message too late.

Yes, I am using `select()` beforehand, yet it still returns 1 even when the peer has shut down.

As a workaround, I can perform a 0-byte-read with `recv()` directly before calling `send()`, that tells me "Connection OK" (-1) or "Peer shutdown" (0) and does pretty much the job:

```
int readTest = recv( mySD, NULL, 0, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_PEEK );
```

But from the semantic standpoint, it does "feel" wrong to *read* when I actually want *sending*, what I actually want is a mere *test*. So is there a command such as "socket status" where I can directly figure out what I need? The kind of thing `recv()` uses internally?

Comment: From a semantic standpoint, it does *not* feel wrong to read when you actually want to *check if the peer has shut down and send afterwards*. If you want to know whether your peer has shut down, then you need to find it out, simply with a read call in this case.

Comment: Show the call to `select()` that you have. It's possible that the third set (`exceptfds`) can be used to detect this.

Comment: int selectRes = select( mySD + 1, NULL, &tempSDSet, NULL, &timeout );

Comment: @unwind No. An incoming close is a read event, not an exceptional event.

Comment: Guess I got the whole picture: "Peer close" is a read event, so calling `select()` for _read_ yields "true", therefore I do a read (e.g. with `recv()`) and get "0" which tells me what happened. Thanks all of you for contributing and helping me understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your programs is select based, I believe you register the socket both for read and write fd set. If yes, you would be getting a select return for read fd set and you would be 'recv'ing eventually '0' and hence closing the socket.

Comment: I use different selects for read and write. So you suggest to do something like `select( mySD + 1, &tempSDSet, &tempSDSet, NULL, &timeout );` ? I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: if you have single threaded process, you must have a very strong reason to have two selects separately for read and write fds.

Comment: The application is build that way. Usually, it only sends messages to a server, an only here and then it must read the answer of a former request. So reading and writing are handled separately, and are combined on a higher level as a "request operation" if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a reason why protocols on top of sockets do implement ping-pong mechanisms?

Best, Peter

Comment: That is not an answer. There are people who might downvote you, just saying.

Comment: Grammatically speaking you are completely right. Thanks for the note and also for not downgrading. However, questions can imply answers, like in this case I intended to say: "Look, saying whether you are connected or not on the socket layer is considered to be a nontrivial business, otherwise people would not have bothered to implement pings and pongs. It is not reliable. Easiest way for you to go would be to include a simple ping-pong mechanism." Fair enough?

Comment: I think there are comments for question like these.

Comment: @ilmiacs: I really would like to implement a request-answer protocol on application level (thus: I send a message, the peer must acknowledge _every_ receipt). However, the protocol to deal with is already given and fixed, and it does not provide such things (I send a message and get no answer), so I must rely on TCP mechanisms. Those messages can happen once every minute (or even longer), so signaling an error to the user (LED on the device) should happen asap, thus immediately after a message has (not) been sent, and not after the _next_ message.

Comment: Okay, convinced. I'm quite new here. Thanks for the advice. Can I delete my "Answer"?

Comment: Imho you can leave it. Though it doesn't actually answer to my original question, it considers the problem "connection control" on a different level. So when people _have_ the possiblility to design their own high level protocol, that might be a good hint. Consider as well [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne) which I find quite useful.